# Are the Online Daily Objectives different for everyone?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Does GTA Online share the same daily objectives for each player or are they all different for everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off other forums that I've found, it seems that they are **different for everyone**.

- [Se7ensins](http://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/daily-objectives-their-rewards.1338682/?jdfwkey=qrqa42)
- [GameFaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/805602-grand-theft-auto-online/71715796)
- [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GTAV/comments/2zj4mx/does_everyone_get_the_same_daily_objectives/)

They all mention it is different for everyone.